# revalue data with multiple conditions in r

Tags: r, vector, filter, dplyr, string-concatenation

I extracted a `vector` from a `dataframe`.
The `df` looks like this:

```
from  type
 23    U
 25    U
 30    S
 32    S
 50    T
 60    T
```

and the `vector`:

```
vec<-c("23","30","50")
```

Now I want to search for the values defined by the `vector` in the `df`. 
If the value in the `df` is part of the `vector` then I want to paste the `type` variable in front of the `from` variable.

I tried to look up the `vector` with `dplyr::filter`.

```
df<-df %>% filter(from %in% vec && type=="U") %>% mutate(from=paste(type,from,sep=""))
```

Now I don't know how to proceed as my approach doesn't work out. Not sure whether a `if-else` statement would be more appropriate.

expected results are:

```
from  type
 U23   U
 25    U
 S30   S
 32    S
 T50   T
 60    T
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(from = ifelse(from %in% vec, paste0(type, from), from))

  from type
1  U23    U
2   25    U
3  S30    S
4   32    S
5  T50    T
6   60    T
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
 from  type
 23    U
 25    U
 30    S
 32    S
 50    T
 60    T", h =T)


vec<-c("23","30","50")
```

Comment: Hello, I used your code. Now I noticed a mistake. Somehow the value in ''from'' column changes, too. Even if it is not part of the vector.

Anybody an idea on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do,

```
df$from[df$from %in% as.numeric(vec)] <- paste0(df$type[df$from %in% as.numeric(vec)], 
                                                df$from[df$from %in% as.numeric(vec)])
```